# IE 11 <main> not recognized as a block element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Does IE 11 have a box-sizing: border-box issue?

Here is the presumed structure. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnao65tf/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="mainContent">
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left {
  background: tomato;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  bakcground: grey;
  height: 200px;
}
.content {
 margin-left: 175px;
 background: blue;
 height: 200px;
}
.mainContent {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  background: orange;
  height: 200px;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  background: pink;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Here is the practical [version](http://gw.thisbetterworkbetter.com/groton-wellness/symptoms-conditions/dental/mercury-toxicity/) in use.

As you can see in this [comparison](https://crossbrowsertesting.com/users/public/ica551b1753efd17/screenshots/z349c315690ca159a83c/z638cb875dd6f6519a73/comparison/z9adfae35865cd5b2699?mode=single&user=ica551b1753efd17&tr=z349c315690ca159a83c&target=z638cb875dd6f6519a73&base=z9adfae35865cd5b2699&public=true) the main container width that has the margin applied to it is greater than 100% on the wrapper element which then stacks the columns. Almost like the box-sizing method isn't applying to it? Not sure what I am missing here.

I'm also unsure of meaning of "Element is hidden in base browser but not target." seen on the [comparison](https://crossbrowsertesting.com/users/public/ica551b1753efd17/screenshots/z349c315690ca159a83c/z638cb875dd6f6519a73/comparison/z9adfae35865cd5b2699?mode=single&user=ica551b1753efd17&tr=z349c315690ca159a83c&target=z638cb875dd6f6519a73&base=z9adfae35865cd5b2699&public=true) page.

Answer (score 1):

As seen [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jan/12/main-HTML5-Tag-not-working-in-Internet-Explorer-91011).  `<main></main>` is not recognized as a block element in EI11. Adding `display: block` remedied the issue.

```
main {
    display: block;
}
```